# Xsd location in embedded Java SE server

Tags: java, soap, jetty, jax-ws, embedded-jetty

I use the built-in server in Java SE 6 for SOAP service. I have a WSDL with XSD.

My code:

```
Endpoint.publish ("http://localhost:9999/event-ws/wsdl", new SoapImpl ());
```

But when I open this WSDL in SOAP UI, it says it can not find XSD (`localhost:9999/event-ws/test.xsd`): server return 404.

XSD and WSDL are together in a folder.

#### Edit1:

wsdl from local file:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/extern/">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="test.xsd"
    namespace="http://localhost/extern/event" />
  <xsd:element name="getAccountChangeTaskEvents">
    ....
```

I generated an interface from wsdl (and xsd) using the wsimport and wrote implementation.

#### Edit2:

wsdl from browser:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/extern/">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="test.xsd" namespace="http://localhost/extern/event"/>
<xsd:element name="getAccountChangeTaskEvents">
<xsd:complexType>
   ....
```

#### Edit3

But web-service successfully deployed and I can use it.

Comment: Does the WSDL imports the XSD?

Comment: Can you open that XSD in browser? Look into the WSDL from browser and try to open XSD, let me know what will happen

Comment: Oh, unfortunately xsd open in the browser I can not. That's the problem. I go on on url which is registered in wsdl for xsd (http://localhost:9999/event-ws/test.xsd) and get 404 error.

Comment: So thats the problem, SOAP UI isn't lying to you :) Show me the part from WSDL (your local file) where you importing the XSD.

Comment: Can you also put the import of XSD WSDL part but from deployed service? Just copy from your browser.

Comment: Did it. Apparently, they are the same.

Comment: Well they definitely should not be the same, in the browser you should see something like this: `<xsd:import namespace="http://localhost/extern/event" schemaLocation="http://yourhost.com:8080/YourService/Service?xsd=test.xsd"/>` check the server logs why it is not picking your XSD correctly. The quick fix would be move all types from XSD to WSDL directly, it would solve the problem, I can't tell at the moment why the importing not working.

Comment: Thank you, I will think.